# how to count repeation of value from multiple columns?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have access table (called year2016) with months columns and client name rows and the worker name who did the jop in this month. i want sql code that give me how many clients every worker dealed with by month.

the table look like this:

```
client   month01    month02     month03   month04 .......
1         john       adam        sarah      john
2         adam        adam        john      sarah
.
.
.
```

I am new to sql i tried this (meanwhile for two months) but it give me error:

```
SELECT a.name, c1.count, c2.count
FROM (SELECT month01 AS name FROM year2016 UNION SELECT month02 FROM year2016) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT month01, COUNT(*) AS count FROM year2016 GROUP BY month01) c1
ON a.name=c1.month01
LEFT JOIN (SELECT month02, COUNT(*) AS count FROM year2016 GROUP BY month02) c2
On a.name=c2.month02;
```

I expect to get table like this:

```
worker     month01     month02    month03    month04 ......
john           8           14        5          9
adam           12            6          5        3
sarah           4            6         34        56
```

Comment: What error did it give?  Always list the error details when asking a question.

Comment: It is most likely that you need to place parenthesis around the first JOIN before attempting to add a second JOIN, like `((SELECT ...) a LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...) c1 ON ...) LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...) c2 ON a.name = c2.month02`.  Do you see the extra set of parenthesis I added?

Comment: Having the months as columns with the worker name as the value for those columns is not properly normalized.  Honestly, this would be a lot easier if the table were normalized so that it had columns like `[client], [month], [worker]` so that the rows were like `1, 01, john`; `1, 02, adam`; `2, 01, adam`; ...  Then you could utilize other SQL statement types like TRANSFORM... PIVOT and other aggregate forms without having to recombine with UNIONS and write separate subqueries for each month, etc.  It is more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be to first union together all month columns into a single column, and then pivot by month:

```
SELECT
    worker,
    SUM(IIF(month='month01', 1, 0)) AS month01,
    SUM(IIF(month='month02', 1, 0)) AS month02,
    SUM(IIF(month='month03', 1, 0)) AS month03,
    SUM(IIF(month='month04', 1, 0)) AS month04,
    SUM(IIF(month='month05', 1, 0)) AS month05,
    SUM(IIF(month='month06', 1, 0)) AS month06,
    SUM(IIF(month='month07', 1, 0)) AS month07,
    SUM(IIF(month='month08', 1, 0)) AS month08,
    SUM(IIF(month='month09', 1, 0)) AS month09,
    SUM(IIF(month='month10', 1, 0)) AS month10,
    SUM(IIF(month='month11', 1, 0)) AS month11,
    SUM(IIF(month='month12', 1, 0)) AS month12
FROM
(
    SELECT month01 AS worker, 'month01' AS month FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month02, 'month02' FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month03, 'month03' FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month04, 'month04' FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month05, 'month05' FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month06, 'month06' FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month07, 'month07' FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month08, 'month08' FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month09, 'month09' FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month10, 'month10' FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month11, 'month11' FROM year2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT month12, 'month12' FROM year2016
) t
GROUP BY
    worker;
```

But note that your data is not normalized at all.  The subquery I have aliased as `t` above is really how you should be storing your data in Access.  So, try to change your design if you can.

Comment: Notice that this is for MS Access.  That SQL is not compatible, the CASE statement in particular.

Comment: @Perkins Thanks for pointing that out.  Access has a peculiar syntax, easy to make this mistake without testing.

Comment: @Perkins, I have [suggested the Access team](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) upgrade to ANSI standards. One item involves integration of `CASE`. Please vote if you can.

Comment: @Parfait +3 votes to your ticket.  I find it especially strange Access is so different, given that it is a Microsoft product.

Comment: @Parfait  Honestly, I really like Access about as much as I hate it :), but I don't see Access being changed on that level since there are so many other quirky, old-paradigm aspects that also need updating.  I'd rather see MS put effort into producing an Access replacement that implements full .Net support and implementation of acceptable design patterns and security, etc.  Perhaps then could they implement ANSI-SQL, but until then I would cringe at the incompatibilities of a product with limited future potential.